# ajax post Request 401 (Unauthorized) API Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm try to request an ajax Post with laravel, they provided me a API with username and password authorization. how can I solve this.

here my code below.

```js
$("#login_page").submit(function (e) {
   $.ajax({
       url: "https://api.seasolutions.ph/frontend/login/",
       type: "POST",
       headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Basic ' + '***=',
       },

       data: $("#login_page").serialize(), //only input
       success: function (response) {
           console.log(response);
       }
   });
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Can you see the headers being sent in the Network tab?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your `csrf_token` I think.

Here's the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

```
headers: {
   'Authorization':'Basic ' + '***=',
   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```

If it doesn't work, you need to add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` into your main blade file.